# How to enable HTML client-side SQL database in embedded webkit app (test app on github)

Tags: objective-c, database, cocoa, macos, webkit

I've got a super simple little OS X app with a minimal embedded webkit view that needs client-side SQL database support enabled. I've put the [test app up on github](http://github.com/subblue/webview-local-storage) but just can't get the client-side storage working.

I'm using Xcode v3.2.3 with the WebKit framework it provides, but have also tried using the webkit nightly without luck.

I'm setting the preferences via a 'web' outlet:

```
WebPreferences *prefs = [web preferences];
[prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"/tmp"];
[prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"/tmp"];
[prefs setDatabasesEnabled:YES];
[prefs setLocalStorageEnabled:YES];
[prefs setDeveloperExtrasEnabled:YES];
```

If anyone could fork the app on github or point out what else I need to be doing, it'd be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm trying to do the same thing, and having no luck.

Comment: Still no word on this?  BTW, your link to Github is dead, and your project pages don't list anything that sounds remotely like this project... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Local databases should be done with a javascript you run in the HTML, 
[HTML5 Databases tutorial](http://www.weboshelp.net/webos-tutorials/156-palm-webos-html5-database-storage-tutorial)

You could also try using sqlLite in your app, or core data but I think you want to access it through your HTML?