# How to get localStorage to work in a WebView in Xcode?

Tags: macos

I've got a WebView in a Max OSX Cocoa Application in Xcode. This WebView is attempting to use HTML5's `localStorage` to save some data. It's technically working as expected (the data is getting/setting fine while the application is running), it's just not persisting when the application is closed and then reopened.

Any ideas on how to get `localStorage` to persist as expected?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you using the per-session or the persistent local storage API? It's worth checking that first...

Comment: Using `localStorage` (not `sessionStorage`). Found some more useful info, will amend my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while back we were working on implementing local storage in the webview of an iPhone app, and what we found is that it does not work.  Although local storage will work on the iPhones regular browser.   We ended up doing what we needed natively within the app itself.

Looks like these guys came to the same conclusion:

[How do I enable Local Storage in my WebKit-based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527905/how-do-i-enable-local-storage-in-my-webkit-based-application/4608549#4608549)

Caveat lecture:  When we were trying this solution it was before iPhone 4 was released.

Comment: `[prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"~/Library/Application Support/MyApp"];` That works. I've heard private APIs aren't allowed in the Apple App Store but I guess I'll cross that bridge when I get to it :) Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be wiped out on program exit and re-entry. This is a problem for long term persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it persists by default for me in webview of an iPhone app. Even after phone restart it works fine.