# Unable to save in NSWebView's local storage

Tags: objective-c, macos, uiwebview, webkit, local-storage

I am working as an iOS Developer, although I am new in Mac Developmet. I have a problem with my wrapper mac App. The local storage works fine in 10.9 OS but it is not working in 10.7. Is there any obvious reason about this or I have to find alternative ways. I tried this solution [localStorage not persisting in OSX app (Xcode 4.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609644/localstorage-not-persisting-in-osx-app-xcode-4-3) and works only for 10.9. Any ideas?