# How to enable local store in Cocoa WebView using Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, webview

In this question [How do I enable Local Storage in my WebKit-based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527905/how-do-i-enable-local-storage-in-my-webkit-based-application) they show how to do it in objc, but that methods (nor similar) seems to NOT be present from Swift.