# Set location of webview database (websql) in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I have a websql database, that I'd like to point to the same location as local storage.

I can easily set the localstorage path with this (private) method:

```
    [preferences _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:savePath];
```

However I can't find something similar for the WebSQL database. I read this post, but am confused what to do:

[Can a WebKit-based Mac app use HTML5 databases from Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022650/can-a-webkit-based-mac-app-use-html5-databases-from-safari)

I added WebDatabaseDirectory to my plist and pointed it to ~/Library/Application Support/MyApp but that doesn't seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that theme, but maybe the following hints help you come forward:

Check the superclasses in the documentation for a command.
WebSQL is no longer maintained since 2013, so I think using it, is not the best idea.
SQLite could be used with core data.

I also checked and read your links, where
"When you aren't using Safari, it appears that databases are written to ~/Library/WebKit/Databases..." 
and
"... set the WebDatabaseDirectory default to make your application use the same directory structure as Safari, which appears to be ~/Library/Safari/Databases".

A database should not be stored in Application Support.